# Custom sine function in Functional Programming

Tags: haskell, trigonometry

Please help, I've been trying to get this code to work but I can't find the errors. Below is my code

```
sumToN f x 1 = f (x 1)
sumToN f x n = f x n + f x (n-1)

facOfN 0 = 1
facOfN n = n * facOfN (n-1) sgfr

sineApprox x n = ((-1) ^ n) * ((x ** (2*n+1))/facOfN(2*n+1)
sine x n = sumToN (sineApprox x n)
```

When I try to load the file I get the following error.

```
ERROR file:F:\sine.hs:8 - Syntax error in expression (unexpected `;', possibly due to bad layout)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis at the end of the `sineApprox` line.

Comment: Is this Hugs? In ghci, the error is rather more descriptive: `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said in the comments, you've forgotten to close a paren. It'll work like that:

```
sineApprox x n = ((-1) ^ n) * ((x ** (2*n+1))/facOfN(2*n+1))
```

Note that this problem would have been obvious with a better text editor. Being a beginner, I suggest you switch to [iHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell), which has a very simple interface and yet reasonably powerful editor features.

The problem would *also* have been obvious if you hadn't used so many unnecessary parens. The following can be omitted just like that, some can be replaced with `$`. While we're at style...

```
sumToN f x n   -- checking ==1 is not safe in general
    | n<=1       = f $ x 1
    | otherwise  = f x n + f x (n-1)

facOfN = product [1..n]

sineApprox x n = (-1)^n * x**(2*n+1) / facOfN (2*n+1)

sine x = sumToN . sineApprox x
```

On another note: in general, you should always use type signatures. This code actually has problems because all the counter variables are automaticall floating point (like everything else). They should really be `Int`s, which requires a conversions in the factorial<sup>†</sup>:

```
sumToN :: Num n => (Int -> n) -> Int -> n
sumToN f x n
    | n<1        = 0
    | otherwise  = f x n + f x (n-1)

facOfN :: Num n => Int -> n
facOfN = product [1 .. fromIntegral n]

sineApprox :: Fractional n => n -> Int -> n
sineApprox x n = (-1)^n * x^(2*n+1) / facOfN (2*n+1)

sine 
sine x = sumToN . sineApprox x
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>BTW, explicitly using factorials is almost always a bad idea, as the numbers quickly get intractibly huge. Also, you're doing a lot of duplicate work. Better multiply as you add along!</sub>